# number of green and red edge colorings on a complete graph such that there's at least one triangle with $2$ green sides and $1$ red side

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

**Problem Description**

Let $K_n$ be a complete graph on $n \ge 3$ labelled vertices $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$. If every edge must be colored either green or red, then how many $N$ distinct ways can the edges be colored such that there exists three vertices $x,y,z$ where $\{ x,y \}$ is green, $\{ y,z \}$ is green, and $\{ x,z \}$ is red?

**My Effort Thus Far...**

If $k$ is the number of red edges in the graph, then we must have $1 \le k \le {n \choose 2}-2$ in order for three such vertices $x,y,z$ to even exist. I've also determined that three such vertices *must always exist* whenever $1 \le k < n-1$ (in the interest of space, I will omit the proof). Hence,

$$ N \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} {{n \choose 2} \choose k}$$

Furthermore, when $k=n-1$ there are exactly ${{n \choose 2} \choose n-1} - n$ ways to color the edges so that three such vertices exist. Thus,

$$ N \ge - n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {{n \choose 2} \choose k}$$

For $n-1 < k \le {n \choose 2}-2$, the solution gets tricky because, for any particular $k$, multiple configurations of edge colorings will both rule in and rule out the existence of three such vertices. When examining this by hand for small $n$, I counted the number of graphs in each isomorphism class that allowed three such vertices to exist. Of course, for large $n$ this impractical. I would like to derive some formula that is a function of $n$.

Can anyone $(a)$ help me out, $(b)$ offer potential paths forward, or $(c)$ suggest related theorems or papers to look into? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: complementary counting. What must the graph look like if there does not exist $x,y,z$ with $\{x,y\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ green, but $\{x,z\}$ red?

Comment: complementary counting seems like a more challenging approach because one must count colorings in which *every* collection of three distinct vertices forms a triangle with either $(1)$ all red sides, $(2)$ all green sides, or $(3)$ two red sides and one green side. perhaps it is not so challenging. i will give it some more thought. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: My second hint is to draw some graphs (in your mind, or on paper) which satisfy the complementary property; no triangle has two green edges and a third red edge. Say, draw a graph on eight vertices with eight green edges (no need to draw the red edges).

Comment: $N(3)=3$. Can you work out $N(4)$, and then consult the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I did what you said, and I noticed every graph satisfying the complementary property consists of $\ge 1$ connected components such that each connected component is a complete graph of its own (using only green edges and treating red edges as if they don't exist). So, counting the number of edge colorings satisfying the complementary property appears to reduce to *counting the number of ways one can construct $m$ disconnected complete graphs from $n$ vertices for $m=1,2,3,...,{n \choose 2}$.* Does this sound like the right idea, or this there still something you see that I don't?

Comment: Your last comment is exactly the right idea :) I think your insight leads to an answer involving Stirling numbers of the second kind and principle of inclusion exclusion. There is also probably a good answer using EGF. I will write an answer.

Comment: Yeah i immediately noticed that as well. Counting the colorings satisfying the complementary property is equivalent to counting the number of equivalence relations on a set of $n$ elements.